# Configuring CDT without too many configurations

Tags: eclipse, makefile, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I am working on an embedded C project that is somewhat complex (several hundred source files divided into 3 sub-projects). Currently we are using eclipse CDT to generate makefiles and build our project. The advantage of this is that there is no duplication between eclipse configuration and the makefiles. Now I need to create several build types:

- a DEBUG build with some compiler options such as `-g -O0` and a few macros defined
- a PRODUCTION build with `-03`
- a TEST build with some various compiler options and macros defined

Given that I already have 3 eclipse projects this would result in 9 sets different Eclipse configurations that have to be updated any time we need to make a change that affects all the types and projects.

Is there another solution that will allow us to develop in Eclipse--and have it correctly reflect the value of macros based on the desired build type--without needing to maintain so many configurations?

Is there some trick to Eclipse CDT configurations to make this easier? Perhaps I could use a tool such as CMake which has the ability to generate  Eclipse CDT files?

Comment: You can create multiple build configurations for a single project. Check [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_settings_tool.htm). But only one can be made active at a time.

Comment: This is what I have now, but I will end up with 9 configurations and each configuration generates its own set of makefiles, I estimate that will be about 400 mk files. Granted eclipse does have an option to edit all the build configurations as a group it still seems a little silly that if I change a compiler option for all configurations I will need to commit 400 changed files to my repo.

Comment: You could write your own makefile (one per project), and define the configurations to just invoke different targets in the same makefile.